# How to apply Baidu conversion code for mobile and desktop?

Tags: tracking, conversions, baidu

I've got 2 landing pages on the same site. 1 for mobile and 1 for desktop, and it's the same campaign. So the first page visitors arrive at is the mobile-redirect page. Depending if their accessing the site through mobile or desktop they'll get redirected to the correct version of the Landing page. So my questions are:

Baidu asks for a site URL to generate the conversion snippet - do I use website.com or website.com/mobile-redirect?

The landing pages I have consists of 2 pages and conversion occurs on the second page - so do I just paste the Baidu conversion snippet onto page 2 for both versions?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you paste the Baidu conversion snippet onto page 2 for both versions because Baidu needs to know where the conversion comes from in order to properly notify the system.

I've never used the Baidu tracking, but this is how normal tracking system work.